# ADOdb is returning both column names and number indexes

Tags: php, adodb-php

ADOdb `fetchRow` output:

```
Array
(
 [0] => ABC
    [NAME] => ABC
    [1] => 33
 [AGE] => 33
    [3] => M
 [GENDER] => M
    [4] => LA
 [CITY] => LA
    [5] => OH
 [STATE] => OH
)
```

How can I get the number-index only output:

```
Array 
(
 [0] => ABC
 [1] => 33
 [2] => M
 [3] => LA
 [4] => OH

)
```

Or the name-index only output? :

```
Array
(
    [NAME] => ABC
    [AGE] => 33
    [GENDER] => M
    [CITY] => LA
    [STATE] => OH
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Numeric indexes – use $connection->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_NUM).
2. Associative indexes – the keys of the array are the names of the fields (in upper-case). Use $connection->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC).
3. Both numeric and associative indexes – use $connection->SetFetchMode(ADODB_FETCH_BOTH).

The default is ADODB_FETCH_BOTH for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Respectively

```
$ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_NUM;
```

and

```
$ADODB_FETCH_MODE = ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC;
```

From the manual:

**If no fetch mode is predefined, the fetch mode defaults to ADODB_FETCH_DEFAULT. The behaviour of this default mode varies from driver to driver, so do not rely on ADODB_FETCH_DEFAULT. For portability, we recommend sticking to ADODB_FETCH_NUM or ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC. Many drivers do not support ADODB_FETCH_BOTH.**

Comment: Note: If you have called `SetFetchMode`, then `$ADODB_FETCH_MODE` will **no longer** be read.